# Problem with cutting angles using white objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, shapes

So I am very new to Illustrator, as in I started using the program 4 days ago.
I've been creating a logo for a business card (for a class project), and Im running into some problems that I don't know how to google.

Here is a small album of my issue 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6YCx.jpg

The first picture is my logo (still a rough), the second is to show the paths, and layers, third picture is the problem itself, and last is my progress so far.
So, my problem arose when, as you can see in the fourth picture, I wanted to cut off the edges on lines to get a smooth angle on both the bottom of the R and on the lens of the "camera." (The top circle part I think I can solve pretty easy as it was done the most recently).

I didn't and still don't know how to solve that problem other than hiding it with a white object, but now that has come back to bite me because everything is grouped so I am unable to get rid of those "artifacts" while keeping the smooth angle.

Any help you can provide would be awesome!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about software training, not design. For the record, if you **connect your paths** they tend to join better. Random unconnected strokes always cause join issues.

Comment: Hi user41925, I would take a look at using the pathfinder options to control which parts of the object show. You can see the adobe help document: [Combining objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/combining-objects.html). You can also find many video training tutorials online.